# Python – How do I convert an ASCII string into UTF-8?

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, ascii, decode

I am using a package in python that returns a string using ASCII characters as opposed to unicode (eg. returns 'serÃ©' as opposed to seré).

Given this is python 3.8, the string is actually encoded in unicode, the package just seems to output it as if it were ASCII. As such, when I try to perform x.decode('utf-8') or x.encode('ascii'), neither work. Is there a way to make python treat the string as if it were ASCII, such that I can decode it to unicode? Or is there a package that can serve this purpose.

I am relatively new to python so I apologise if my explanation is unclear. I am happy to clarify things if needed.

##### Code

```py
from spanishconjugator import Conjugator as c  
verb = c().conjugate('pasar', 'preterite', 'indicative', 'yo')
print(verb)
```

This returns the string 'pasÃ©' where it should return 'pasé'.

##### Update

From further searching and from your answers, it appears to be an issue to do with single 2-byte UTF-8 (é) characters being literally interpreted as two 1-byte latin-1 (Ã©) characters (nothing to do with ASCII, my mistake).

Managed to fix it with:

```py
verb.encode('latin-1').decode('utf-8')
```

Thank you to those that commented.

Comment: UTF-8 is a superset of ASCII, so you shouldn't have any issues going from ASCII to UTF-8. Please post the minimum reproducable code as specified in the guidelines if you want further help.

Comment: Unless you want to debug the specific package, it is actually irrelevant. Please provide the “ASCII string" *as a valid literal* and the desired Unicode result.

Comment: You're mistaken. 1) Every ASCII string already is UTF-8, 2) ASCII doesn't contain the characters "Ã" or "©".

Comment: Note that this seems like a serious deficiency for a package that is obviously aware of non-ASCII characters. This might be using outdated code from Python2 or otherwise lack maintenance. Consider to reach out to the package maintainers to get this fixed in the package itself.

Comment: Please keep Questions and Answers separate. The solution does not belong in the question.

Comment: For the record, [this appears to be a bug in the library](https://github.com/Benedict-Carling/spanish-conjugator/issues/26).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the input string contains the raw byte ordinals (such as `\xc3\xa9`/`Ã©` instead of `é`) use `latin1` to *encode* it to bytes verbatim, then *decode* with the desired encoding.

```py
>>> "pasÃ©".encode('latin1').decode()
'pasé'
```